# NSRangeException with PHFetchResult

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I am developing an iOS App that fetches videos from the Photo gallery and it always worked. I just tested the app on a different device (this is not the first on which I test) and it crashes while I use the retrieved data and I don't understand why...

Here is my code :

```
self.videosAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: nil)

if self.videosAssets != nil {
    for i in 0..<self.videosAssets!.count {
        if let video = self.videosAssets!.objectAtIndex(i) as? PHAsset {
            self.videos.append(Video(asset: video))
        }
    }
}
```

It fetches 221 videos but it crashes when i == 59.

Here is the error I get :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
```

Comment: No, it does not crash at `i == 59`, it crashes at index 0. Are you sure that is the code that is actually causing the error / crash?

Comment: I realized after that I did not test the Video constructor... I think that the app crashes here. I will test it on Monday

Answer (score 0):

```
self.videosAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: nil)

if let videoAssets = self.videosAssets {
   videoAssets.forEach { video in 
      if video as? PHAsset { self.videos.append(Video(asset: video)) }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing the Video constructor, it was the problem. For some reason, when I call `let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResourcesForAsset(asset)`, it returns me an empty array and this is where the app was crashing.

Sorry for this useless post, maybe it will help someone...